# Magento 2 apply promotion with specific dates without coupon code?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

Is this possible? It appears that you can auto-generate codes and have them expire within a certain date range. That appears to work fine.

Additionally, magento docs says you can add a specific coupon and have it start and end at anytime.
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-coupon.html

Although this has never worked for me because the to and from range are always grayed out when i try this? Perhaps i'm doing something wrong?

Although it would be nice to know how to work specific coupons within a date range. I would be happy knowing that we can apply a promotion without any time of coupon just for a specific time period. Hope that makes sense. I look forward to your responses. Thank you.